# Two COUNT() columns in a SQL query, one for IN/INNER JOIN and one for NOT IN/LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, ingres

Is it possible to create a query where you can have two **COUNT()** columns where one column is for something like **IN()** and another one for something like **NOT IN()** and also just by using **JOIN**?

For instance, I have a table **tbl_a** and **tbl_b**. In a single query I want to have 1 **COUNT()** column for rows existing in both tables. And another **COUNT()** column for rows not existing in **tbl_b** but existing in **tbl_a**.

```
sample in **tbl_a**:
|trans_id|amount |
|--| --- | --- |
|001 | 100.00 |
|002 |250.00|
|003 |300.00 |

sample in **tbl_b**:
|trans_id|ticket_no |
|--| --- | --- |
|001 |X0001|
|002 |X0002|


and my expected output:
|in_a_and_b|not_in_b|
|--| --- | --- |
|2|1|
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff done adding sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a key that matches rows in the tables uniquely, you can use:

```
select count(*) as in_a,
       count(b.col) as in_a_and_b,
       (count(*) - count(b.col)) as in_a_not_b
from tbl_a a left join
     tbl_b b
     on a.col = b.col
```